# Find everything after first comma in lines and remove it

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I have a file containing a bunch of lines like this `blabla-any-characters**,**numbers-and-characters` 
I would like to keep everything before the **first** comma and remove everything else.
Any hint how to do this with awk or sed?
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use sed like this:

```
sed -i.bak 's/,.*$//' file
```

`,.*$` will match anything after first comma and will replace it by an empty string.

`-i.bak` is for inline editing in sed.

Comment: This works! Thanks. I have to wait 4 min. to accept it

Comment: I am used to doing 's/\(.*\),.*/\1/'  Can you help provide some pointers on how your regex works ? Some web links will help too.

Comment: I wrote in my answer an explanation i.e. `,.*$` will match anything after first comma and `//` will replace it by empty string.

Answer (score 4):

Try this with cut:

```
cut -d ',' -f 1 file
```

Answer (score 2):

For `awk` you could use:

```
awk -F"," '{print $1}' file
```

Which will delimit each record using a comma and then only print the first element.

Comment: This works too, thank you. But **anubhava** was faster!

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with `awk` relatively easily.

```
$ cat test.txt
blabla-any-characters**,**numbers-and-characters
john,smith
hello,world

$ awk -F',' '{print $1}' test.txt
blabla-any-characters**
john
hello
```